# How to initialize generic type using Factory Design Pattern in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, generics, design-patterns

I need to initialize generic type of the class but I couldn't do it. As far as I did research, factory design pattern is way better to make this generic type initialization but I don't know how.

Here's my generic service;

```
@Service
public abstract class GaService<Entity extends Ga<? extends Play>, DTO extends GaDTO<? extends PlayDTO>> {

    @Autowired
    protected GaRepository<Entity> repository;

    @Autowired
    protected Mapper<Entity, DTO> mapper;

    public DTO initialize(){
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        repository.save(entity);
        return mapper.toDTO(entity);
    }
```

As you notice my `new Entity()` is giving an error and to achieve this, I need to find a way to initialize Entity. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here:

First option: define an abstract factory method to be implemented in the concrete classes:

```
protected abstract Entity newEntity();
```

Second option: pass the class to the `initialize` method:

```
public DTO initialize(Class<Entity> entityClass){
    Entity entity = entityClass.newInstance();
    repository.save(entity);
    return mapper.toDTO(entity);
}
```

UPDATE: Third option: pass a `Supplier` the `initialize` method:

```
public DTO initialize(Supplier<Entity> newEntity){
    Entity entity = newEntity.get();
    repository.save(entity);
    return mapper.toDTO(entity);
}
```

Comment: Or pass a factory method (as a `Supplier`) to the `initialize` method.

Comment: @f1sh OK: that's a third

Comment: First option worked perfect!